# preg_match two variables with metacharacters

Tags: regex, pcre, php, posix-ere

I have two string variables which are both file paths. The code that worked used ereg which is deprecated, so I'm trying to rewrite it using preg_match:

Old code that worked:

```
$path1 = quotemeta($path);
ereg("$path1(.*)$", $path2, $matches);
```

Using preg_match which doesn't seem to work:

```
$path1 = quotemeta($path);
preg_match("/$path1(.*)$/", $path2, $matches);
```

It gives

> preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'V' error.

Also, the main thing I'm trying to obtain is $matches[1], which is the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, so I'm thinking I can't really use `substr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are some special-characters in your `$path` variable, those should be escaped -- and they should be escaped considering you are using [PCRE](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) ; and not [POSIX-regex](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php).

This can be done using the [`preg_quote`](http://fr.php.net/preg_quote) function  ; which means your code would look like this :

```
$path1 = preg_quote($path, '/');
preg_match("/$path1(.*)$/", $path2, $matches);
```

In particular, note that PCRE use a delimiter arround the regex -- here, you used a `/` ; this delimiter has to be passed to `preg_quote`, as this function doesn't, by default, escape the `/` character.

The [`quotemeta`](http://fr.php.net/quotemeta) function you were using doesn't quote all the characters that are used by PCRE.

As you are porting some code from POSIX-regex to PCRE, you should take a look at the [PCRE Patterns section of the manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) : PCRE are very powerful, but that power comes with a couple of tricks...

Comment: Wow that totally fixed it! Thanks for making my day!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this one without regular expressions:

```
$pos = strpos($path2, $path);
if ($pos !== false) {
    $match = substr($path2, $pos+strlen($path));
}
```

Comment: I think $match gives me the matched string instead of text that matched the parenthesized subpattern. But this is definitely working code. Thanks.

Comment: @highlightall: Put `$path` in front of it and you have the full match.